# Stripping cookies from image files?

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies, cookieless

I want to achieve cookie free image serving as discussed here :

> http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain

I have created a new sub-domain "static.example.com" serving only images, javscript and css (file serving restrictions made via filesmatch.conf file) , pls. tell how to make it serve cookie free images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal (and probably Wordpress) this can be easily fixed by setting up $cookie_domain = 'www.example.com' value in settings.php.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the cookie specific for the "dynamic" domain, e.g. instead of

```
Set-Cookie:  name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=.example.org
```

do this

```
Set-Cookie:  name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=www.example.org
```

then the client will not send the cookie to retrieve the static content.

It seems this can be done at the Apache level with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). What you probably need is to add a line to your "dynamic" domain like (not tested):

```
Header edit Set-Cookie domain=.example.org domain=www.example.org
```

Comment: I am using drupal and it sets the cookies, I don't want to change drupal config and simply strip cookies from my static subdomain.

Comment: Good to know. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this seems to be the solution I am looking for - can you pls. tell the exact syntax to put into my apache "filesmatch.conf" file for "static.example.com" subdomain to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: That configuration goes for the `www.example.com` domain, instructing the client not to send the cookie to `static.example.com`. It can go anywhere in the configuration, probably you want it in the main <VirtualHost> section

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan for posting Apache solution but I found a better solution posted as answer to this query.

Comment: I supposed there was a way to do it in Drupal, but I don't do Drupal.